# How did Grape juice from My Hero Academia manage to pass the UA entrance exam?

Tags: plot-explanation, my-hero-academia

In *My Hero Academia*, Grape Juice is by far the weakest student in the class and his quirk also doesn't do any damage. In spite of this he's a part of the hero course in UA.

Does any one have any idea how he managed to get in? It's never mentioned that he got in on recommendation too.

Comment: He might be the weakest in the class, but that doesn't mean he didn't meet the minimum requirements.

Comment: How do you think he was able to beat the robots?

Comment: [Answered on Anime.SE](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/40612/how-did-mineta-minoru-get-into-ua).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author has actually commented on this:

> I've received a number of letters asking how on earth [Mineta] managed to pass the Entrance Exam. So I'll take this chance to explain it. First, as Izuku himself said, his quirk is actually quite strong. And remember that the rules of the Entrance Exam was to immobilize or render the villain-bots unable to function anymore, not necessarily to destroy them. As such he could trap them against walls or stick them to the ground, or even plug up their muzzles, to earn points.

[image]